# Problem with $oQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult()

Tags: php, doctrine, query-builder, zend-framework3, laminas-api-tools

I created a table using Doctrine, Zend abigility and php. I have created the Entitiy, Repositry, Resource, Resource  Factory, and the dispature. However, when I do the CRUD functions . I am not able to get the result "$oQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult()" as an Entity object , I am only able to get it as an arrav "$oQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult()"...I want to get the query as an entity object, so what could be the solution?!!
for more information: I am using serealization in array as Hydrator Service in Zend apigility and HalJson as a Content Negotiation Selector .. we are also using vueJS as a frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your module.config.php files related to the respective entity maybe check the path as well. I hope that will help:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my Problem! :)
the problem was in the module.config.php... I had to point to the entity class instead of the given path by apigility!

Comment: happy to help:)